# Question about the proof of $\bar H_0(X) \approx H_0(X,x_0)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

> Prove $\bar H_0(X) \approx H_0(X,x_0)$ (Reduced homology groups)

I'm reading Rotman's Algebraic Topology and I've come across this proof:

$0 \rightarrow \ker \bar \partial_0 \rightarrow S_0(X) \rightarrow^{\bar \partial_0} \bar S_{-1}(X) \rightarrow 0$  If $a \in S_0(X)$ satisfies $\bar \partial_0(a) = 1,$ then $S_0(X) = \ker \bar \partial_0 \oplus \langle a \rangle$ and $\langle a \rangle \approx \Bbb Z$.  But $\bar \partial_0 \partial_1 = 0$ implies that $B_0(X) =$ im $\partial_1 \subset \ker \bar \partial _0$. **Since $S_0(X) = Z_0(X)$, we have ...**

The last line I don't understand, how can $S_0(X) = Z_0(X)$ here?  This would imply that $\bar\partial_0(\gamma) = 0_{\bar S_{-1}(X)}$ for every $\gamma$, but then $S_0(X) = \ker \bar \partial_0 \oplus \langle a \rangle$ would be false.

Can someone explain why this is true?

Comment: Could you please define $Z_0(X)$? There are a few things it could mean here. Perhaps $Z_0(X)$ the group of 0-cycles in normal homology (i.e. not reduced)?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition that I am using for $Z_0(X)$.

Comment: Then $Z_0(X)$ is the $\ker \partial_0$, where $\partial_0$ is the boundary map in the complex $ \dots S_2(X) \overset{\partial_2}{\to} S_1(X) \overset{\partial_1}{\to} S_0(X) \overset{\partial_0}{\to} 0$ Note that my $\partial_0$ is different to your $\bar\partial_0$. Also, perhaps you could provide the rest of the proof, so we can see where we're heading?

Comment: The rest of the proof:  Since  $\dots$ (as above) $\dots$ , we have $H_0(X) = S_0(X) / B_0(X) = (\ker \bar \partial_0 \oplus \langle a \rangle) / B_0(X) \approx (\ker \bar \partial_0 / B_0(X)) \oplus \Bbb Z = \bar H_0(X) \oplus \Bbb Z$  The rest follows from the fact that $H_0(X, x_0)$ is free abelian.  But this actually just seems to show that $H_0(X) \approx \bar H_0(X) \oplus \Bbb Z$ and not the reduced homology groups are isomorphic.

Comment: Fourth line: I mean to say from the fact that $H_0(X)$ is free abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in Rotman, let $(S_*(X),\partial )$ be the singular complex of space X. You will recall the sequence terminates $$ \cdots \xrightarrow{\partial_2} S_1(X) \xrightarrow{\partial_1}S_0(X)\xrightarrow{\partial_0} 0 $$
Thus $\partial_0$ is the zero map and we have $Z_0 (X) \approx ker \,\partial_0 \approx S_0(X)$.